# How to send a message in offline using quickblox sdk ios like whatsapp

Tags: ios, quickblox, quickblox-android

How to send a message in offline using **quickblox**

Answer (score 0):

You can send common message and offline opponent will get push notification. If you mean sending message without login to the chat, you can send message via REST, use next snippet for Android:

```
QBChatMessage qbChatMessage = ...;

QBRestChatService.createMessage(qbChatMessage, true).perform();
```

Comment: Hi @Valentyn. UserA(Internet off) that time trying to send the message UserB. Once UserA internet is on that time UserB receiveing the message or Not like Whats app

Comment: no, you need realize delayed sending messages himself, for example you can collect not sent messages to some collection and use ConnectionListener (https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Login_to_Chat) from QuickBlox Android SDK for listening chat connection state and in callback 'reconnectionSuccessful()' resend this messages again.