# Messages are not delivered acknowledgment when one of users goes background using quickblox like whatsapp

Tags: ios, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have 2 users. UserA is in background and UserB is Online (foreground). UserB send a message to UserA. UserA Receive a message via push notification Using QuickBlox, But acknowlegment does not send to UserB That message will be delivered.

Please give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case was received push notification but not message. QuickBlox not provides mechanism for marking push notification as delivered. You can write this logic manually for example via sending service message via REST as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976576/4850609